# Navigate to the same View. Why Loaded and OnNavigatedTo events aren't called?

Tags: windows-phone-8, view, navigation

Im doing a cloud App(like Skydrive) in Windows Phone 8 , each time I navigate to a different folder I need to reload the FolderView.xaml page to display the content of this folder and I need to add the view to the back stack then I will be able to back to the previous path...
From now when I try to reload the FolderView from the FolderView.xaml.cs page, none event is called...
I don't understand why ? And if you have a solution you are welcome ...

```cs
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

             if (App.ElementSelected != null)
            {
                BdeskElement FolderChoosen = new BdeskElement();
                FolderChoosen = App.ElementSelected;
                Gridentete.DataContext = FolderChoosen;
                GetFiles(FolderChoosen);
            }

        }

 private async void llsElements_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           LongListSelector llselement = null;
            listElementCollection.Clear();

            if (sender != null)
                llselement =(LongListSelector)sender;

                if(llselement.SelectedItem!=null)
                 {
                    BdeskElement bdelement=(BdeskElement)llselement.SelectedItem;

                 if (bdelement.TypeElement==BdeskElement.BdeskTypeElement.Folder)

                     {

                    App.DocLibSelected = null;
                    App.ElementSelected = bdelement;
                    // I navigate to the same view here but nothing happens
                    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/BDocs/FolderView.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));



                     }
                 }
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To navigate to the same page with a new instance, you must change the Uri. For example:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("/Views/BDocs/FolderView.xaml?id={0}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), UriKind.Relative));
```

You can discard that parameter if you don't want/use it.